# React Native Blank MapView

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am starting to "learn" React Native and the first tutorial I see uses a `<MapView />` component. I have tried different ways to show a map but I am not able to.

According to the video itself, it imports `MapView` from `expo`. But after reading some [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/) at the Expo site I changed the import to `react-native-maps`. The error changes but there is no map at all.

When importing `MapView` from `expo` I get an *Invariant Violation* error. But when importing it from `react-native-maps` I get a blank screen on Android and iOS simulators.

I found this online real-time editor with their own iOS / Android / Web simulators. This is the example: https://snack.expo.io/B1H3VWtDH

This is the code. It has two lines...

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

function App() {
  const [region, setRegion] = React.useState({
    latitude: -30.8501718,
    longitude: -50.1700368,
    latitudeDelta: 0.922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  })
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Map screen</Text>
      <MapView
        initialRegion={region}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: please set the apiKey in app.json. and enable the Maps SDK for Android & Maps SDK for iOS at the https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/

Answer (score 0):

After doing "some" research, I was able to fix it by adding CSS-in-JS attributes to the container and the map itself:

According to [this issue's](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/118#issuecomment-192878483) reply on GitHub it worked for me.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

function App() {
  const [region, setRegion] = React.useState({
    latitude: -30.8501718,
    longitude: -50.1700368,
    latitudeDelta: 0.922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Pantalla de inicio</Text>      
      <MapView
        initialRegion={region}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsCompass={true}
        rotateEnabled={true}
        style={styles.map} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    right: 0, 
    bottom: 0, 
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  map: {
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    right: 0, 
    bottom: 0, 
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the MapView was appear in blank.

I added a style:

> style={styles.mapStyle}

to MapView and it works!

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
         style={{ flex: 1 }}
         provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
         showsUserLocation
          initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421}}
          style={styles.mapStyle}
      />
      <StatusBar translucent="false" barStyle="light-content"/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```